# pgfplots: 2d graphics in 3d axis environment

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, 3d

I would like to stack several external 2d plots into a 3d axis environment like the orange and green planes in my example. As the 2d plots are created externally, I am looking for a way to rotate and insert these external graphics accordingly. The `\addplot graphics` command will not provide the desired result as it does not seem to understand 3d, and also `addplot3 graphics` does not work the way I hoped (uncommenting this part will result in an error).
So, is there a way to insert 2d external graphics in a 3d plot and make them appear in the desired perspective?

```
\documentclass[crop,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={70}{30},
    xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,zmin=-1.5,zmax=1.5,
    xlabel=x,
    ylabel=y,
    zlabel=z,
    ]
\filldraw[orange] (axis cs:-1,-1.5,-1.5) -- (axis cs:-1,-1.5,1.5) -- (axis cs:-1,1.5,1.5) -- (axis cs:-1,1.5,-1.5)  -- cycle;
\filldraw[green] (axis cs:0,-1.5,-1.5) -- (axis cs:0,-1.5,1.5) -- (axis cs:0,1.5,1.5) -- (axis cs:0,1.5,-1.5)  -- cycle;
\addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=0,ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,zmin=-1.5,zmax=1.5] {anygraphics};
%\addplot3 graphics[
%       points={
%           (-1,-1.5,1.5) => (0pt,566pt)
%           (-1,1.5,1.5) => (566pt,566pt)
%           (-1,1.5,-1.5) => (566pt,0pt)
%           (-1,-1.5,-1.5) => (0pt,0pt)
%           }
%       ]
%       {anygraphics};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you will have better luck using http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, Pgfplots cannot project 2d content on arbitrary surfaces in 3d space.

That would be a feature request for `pgfplots`.

If you have an image of some orthogonal 3d projection (say, `anygraphics.png`) and want to overlay a 3d axis on top of that 2d image, you can use `\addplot3 graphics`. If that is part of what you want, you may need to elaborate on the phrase "does not work the way I hoped" and provide a reproducable minimal working example.

Comment: In my case, I really want to stack several 2D plots behind each other and not put an axis on a projected 3d plot. I hoped to clarify this by adding the two planes to the picture to demonstrate the desired behaviour. So I'll accept your first sentence as an answer and submit a feature request.